# Error authenticating exit status 1

Tags: drone.io

The plugins/docker (:latest and :17.05) pipeline (with private registry v2) always throws a "**Error authenticating: exit status 1**"

This is the debug log:

```
+ /usr/local/bin/dockerd -g /var/lib/docker
level=warning msg="the \"-g / --graph\" flag is deprecated. Please use \"--data-root\" instead" 
level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found" 
level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 15" 
level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds" 
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit" 
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period" 
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime" 
level=info msg="Loading containers: start." 
level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n, error: exit status 1" 
level=warning msg="Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1" 
level=warning msg="Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: `modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory`, error: exit status 1" 
level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.19.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address" 
level=info msg="Loading containers: done." 
level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization" 
level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=89658be graphdriver=overlay2 version=17.05.0-ce 
level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock" 
level=info msg="Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://<DOMAIN>:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" 
level=info msg="Error logging in to v1 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://<DOMAIN>:5000/v1/users/: dial tcp <IP_ADDRESS>:5000: i/o timeout" 
level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.29/auth returned error: Get https://<DOMAIN>:5000/v1/users/: dial tcp <IP_ADDRESS>:5000: i/o timeout" 
level=fatal msg="Error authenticating: exit status 1"
```

The drone server and drone agent (tried both 0.8 and latest) are running under docker version 17.09.0-ce build afdb6d4 and ubuntu 16.04 with the overlay2 storage driver.

I'am pretty sure it's not an authentication error, as i did login to my private registry with docker login, and also run the pipeline successfully from cli under windows 10 Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

And, this is the publish pipeline:

```
  publish:
    image: plugins/docker:17.05
    username: <USERNAME>
    password: <PASS>
    repo: <DOMAIN>:5000/project
    registry: <DOMAIN>:5000
    tag: ["1", "2"]
    debug: true
```

Comment: Would help more context on this question for example it's seems you are having this issue specifically with this `publish` step in your pipeline but the error you are showing seems to be an issue with the agent trying to connect to the server which then wouldn't be an issue specific to pipeline step.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the issue is with the agent, as i can connect to the registry using a web ui (parabuzzle/craneoperator) and also telnet port 5000. I am not sure how to debug this. I can't ssh into the agent container

Answer (score 0):

Your private registry not config use ssh mode, see the logs

```
level=info msg="Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://<DOMAIN>:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" 
level=info msg="Error logging in to v1 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://<DOMAIN>:5000/v1/users/: dial tcp <IP_ADDRESS>:5000: i/o timeout"
```

plugins/docker support insecure mode, add the insecure: true attr to it will be ok.

```
steps:
- name: docker
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    registry: <DOMAIN>:5000
    repo: <DOMAIN>:5000/project/image
    username: admin
    password: Harbor12345
    insecure: true
```